# SQL Server/ TSQL: query to get large name rows

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table with field Name:

```
TABLE

Name                     WANTED:
-----------------
Done                       This
Barcel
Barcelona                  This
Paris
Parisinos                  This
```

where short name is the bad. I dont need that files

Which is the query in sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you'd want duplicates handled, but this produces the results you wanted.

```
DECLARE @Name TABLE (
     Name VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @Name SELECT 'Done'
INSERT INTO @Name SELECT 'Barcel'
INSERT INTO @Name SELECT 'Barcelona'
INSERT INTO @Name SELECT 'Paris'
INSERT INTO @Name SELECT 'Parisinos'

DELETE t2
from @Name t1
INNER JOIN @Name t2 ON t1.Name LIKE t2.Name + '%'
    AND t1.Name<>t2.Name

SELECT * FROM @Name
```

Comment: I executed this query and it works in my database. is it contempled for 'done'  name too? 'done' is right result

Comment: No, it will not include "Done" as far as I can tell. I believe the '%' makes it so "0" extra characters can match also. You'd want to make sure there is at least one character  for a delete to take place

Comment: You can look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx. Basically do '_%'

Answer (score 1):

This would work for the data you have:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Names') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Names;

CREATE TABLE #Names(Name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #Names
VALUES
      ('Done'),
      ('Barcel'),
      ('Barcelona'),
      ('Paris'),
      ('Parisinos');
```

QUERY:

```
WITH CTE
    AS (SELECT A.Name
            , B.Name AS B_NAME
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY B.Name ORDER BY A.Name DESC) AS RN
        FROM   #Names AS A
             LEFT OUTER JOIN #Names AS B ON A.Name LIKE B.Name+'%')
    SELECT DISTINCT
          Name
    FROM   CTE
    WHERE  RN = 1;
```

RESULTS:

[image]

But if you have the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Names') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Names;

CREATE TABLE #Names(Name VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #Names
VALUES
      ('Done'),
      ('Barcel'),
      ('Barcelona'),
      ('Paris'),
      ('Parisinos'),
      ('Parisians');
```

I'm not sure how you would like to handle it.